# FILTERXML Excel converts value to date

Tags: filterxml

When extracting 2.8018 from the xml below using FILTERXML it gives me a result 2234587 (i suppose it is date).

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`

`<Currency Id="431" fromDate="03/01/2023" toDate="03/01/2023">`

`<Record Date="03/01/2023">`

`<Rate>2.8018</Rate>`

`</Record>`

`</Currency>`

my system delimiter is "," and i have to remain it as it is.
i know that changing the delimiter to "." fixes my problem but i am not allowed to do so.
is there any other solution?

i tried to use NUMBERVALUE function but it failed.